# App crashed when trying to update the retrieved value from SQLite in ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, indexoutofboundsexception

In **Edit_WorkDetails** Activity, it has a `ListView` where the data were actually retrieved from `SQLite`. When the list is clicked, it will `intent` to **Edit_Details** for edit.

This is how my **Edit_WorkDetails** Activity looked like.

[image]

When the save button in Edit_Details clicked, the app crashed.

**Edit_WorkDetails**

```
  listViewUpdate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition=position; // update
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding listview_item_row in the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Get the state's capital from this listview_item_row in the database.
                ID =
                        cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Details.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);


            }
        });

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Edit_Details and populate ListView 
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode==PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("project1");
                ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
                ReceiveProgress = data.getIntExtra("progress", 0);
                ReceiveTimeIn = data.getStringExtra("timeIn");
                ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("timeOut");
                if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                    if (objCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                        objCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);

                } else {  // update list
                    if (objCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                        objCustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

**Edit_Details.java**

```
  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // return values to Edit_WorkDetails and update the list
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                project1 = Project2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                description = Description.getText().toString();
                progress = seekBar.getProgress();
                returnIntent.putExtra("project1", project1);
                returnIntent.putExtra("description", description);
                returnIntent.putExtra("progress", progress);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), progress + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                returnIntent.putExtra("timeIn", timeIn);
                returnIntent.putExtra("timeOut", timeOut);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }


        });

    }
```

**CustomBaseAdapter**

```
 public void changeItem(int mPosition,String Project,String Description,int Percentage,String TimeIn,String TimeOut)
    {
        SearchResults obj = new SearchResults();
        obj.setProject(Project);
        obj.setDescription(" Work Description : " + Description);
        obj.setProgress(" Progress : " + Percentage);
        obj.setTimeIn(" Time In : " + TimeIn);
        obj.setTimeOut(" Time Out : " + TimeOut);
        searchArrayList.set(m,obj);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

AND finally **SearchResult.java**

```
public class SearchResults {

    private String weather = "";
    private String date = "";
    private String status = "";
    private String timeIn="";
    private String timeOut="";
    private String project="";
    private String description="";
    private String progress="";

    public void setWeather(String weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public String getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setTimeIn(String timeIn) {
        this.timeIn = timeIn;
    }

    public String getTimeIn() {
        return timeIn;
    }

    public void setTimeOut(String timeOut){
       this.timeOut=timeOut;
    }

    public String getTimeOut()
    {
        return timeOut;
    }

    public void setProject(String project){
        this.project=project;
    }

    public String getProject()
    {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProgress(String progress){
        this.progress=progress;
    }

    public String getProgress()
    {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description=description;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

}
```

**Error logCat**

```
  Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 2467
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=196609, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.project.myapplication/com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.ActivityB}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
```

**(CustomBaseAdapter.java:101)**

```
 searchArrayList.set(m,obj);
```

**(Edit_WorkDetails.java:141)**

```
 objCustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);
```

Why I will getting such error ? It is impossible to edit the retrieved value from `SQLite` to `ListView` ?

**Database model**

```
 db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_WORKDETAILS + "( " + ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , Project TEXT, WorkDescription TEXT, Percentage Text, TimeIn DATETIME, TimeOut DATETIME, Twd_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Twd_id) REFERENCES "+TABLE_INFO+"(_id) )" );
```

Noted that Twd_id is `foreign key`.

Here my workDetails table

[image]

Now I retrieved the workDetails table data in **Edit_WorkDetails**

**Edit_WorkDetails**

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(getArguments()!=null)
        {
            ID=bundle.getLong("ID");  // ID holds value 1
            BuildEditDetails(ID);
        }

 public void BuildEditDetails(long ID)
    {
         final long id=ID;
         sqlcon.open();
        Cursor cursor=sqlcon.readData(id);

        String[] columns=new String[]{MyDatabaseHelper.Project,MyDatabaseHelper.WorkDescription,MyDatabaseHelper.Percentage
                ,MyDatabaseHelper.TimeIn,MyDatabaseHelper.TimeOut};

        int[] to=new int[]
                {
                        R.id.Project,R.id.Description,R.id.Percentage,R.id.in,R.id.out
                };
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.retrieve_details, cursor, columns, to, 0);

        listViewUpdate.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
```

The following code you may refer to code above

Comment: Your searchArrayList is empty, you cannot use set() for a empty index, use .add() instead.

Comment: @Nanoc thanks!! the app didn't crashed now, but the value still remain the same, not updated

Comment: does the app have a crash report in the log cat?

Comment: @lifeevader If I use `add()` instead of `set()`, my app did not crashed but the value still remain the same, not updated. Then I add a `log.e("Desc",Description)` inside `CustomBaseAdapter` after  `obj.setProject(Project);`, the `log` give me the updated description value, but app crashed

Comment: I just read your question again and noticed `indexoutofbound` exception, it means your array has nothing in it yet you want to access it, show us your database model, where you are creating the table, adding data to it and getting data from it that will give us an overview

Comment: @lifeevader ok, give me 5 minutes

Comment: @lifeevader Done..please help me..

Comment: ok let me look at it

Comment: App not crashed after using `add()`.The issue now is value returned from `Edit_Details` does not update in `Edit_WorkDetails`

Answer (score 1):

You can update your listview data by doing something like customListAdapter.setListData(getListData());
customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();basically when you call `add()` data is added but not refreshed, so try calling `notifyondatasetchanged()` if it does not work call `myListView.invalidateViews();` it will redraw the listview

Comment: what the getListData() refer to ?

Comment: getlistdata is basically your arraylist, so pass your arraylist ther try to refresh your adapter by call `notifiyondatasetchanged()` if it does not work `invalidateviews()` will try to redraw all your views in the list view, `.add()` is adding data to your listview but the adapter is not refreshing so try this chances are it will work

Comment: inform me how it goes, I will be around

Comment: how about customListAdapter

Comment: basically u have it all set up looking at this line ` listViewUpdate.setAdapter(dataAdapter);` so when you add new data call `dataAdapter.notifydatasetchanged()` if nothing works then  use the call `listViewUpdate.invalidataViews()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97221/discussion-between-john-and-life-evader).